# Spark Schema Converter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We use the open sourced API - spark-json-schema (https://github.com/zalando-incubator/spark-json-schema) We want to support decimalType because the data coming in could have 25~29 precision. Does anyone have experience in mapping the field type in a schema to DecimalType?

```scala
val TypeMap = Map(
        "string" -> StringType,
        "number" -> DoubleType,
        "float" -> FloatType,
        "integer" -> LongType,
        "boolean" -> BooleanType,
        "object" -> StructType,
        "array" -> ArrayType
)
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from?

Comment: People submit data in a Jason format and we use schema converter to parse it.